# Using JSP to store images in Mysql and upload the images online

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am still wondering what it is that i am doing wrong,my problem is i dont know if it is my entire sample code which has na error or my connection to the database which has an issues, as of where i stand i am not sure what is making me get this error. (displayed below).I have tried to look here at stack overflow but all i get is loading images using JSP but not adding them to the database. If we have one i couldnt trace please help me with the link. I have included all the libraries needed and my code has no error apart from this output. I came here because i am stranded and need a short review of what you proffesionals think is wrong with my code as done below. I will really appreciate anyhelp given as i am working on a deadline. 
my Database name is

> AppDB
>   I was wondering should i use the name of the table? to INSERT INTO? which is 
>   'contacts'
>
> Error Message
>
> > HTTP Status 404 - /UploadImageOnWeb/uploadServlet type Status report
> >             message /UploadImageOnWeb/uploadServlet description The requested
> >             resource is not available. Apache Tomcat/8.0.23

Thank you

> Java Servlet Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FileUploadDBServlet
 */
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
@WebServlet("/FileUploadDBServlet")
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    // database connection settings
    /*private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/AppDB";
    private String dbUser = "root";
    private String dbPass = "mypassword";*/

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

        InputStream inputStream = null; 


        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
        if (filePart != null) {

            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());


            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        String message = null;  

        try {
            // connects to the database
            /*DriverManager.registerDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);*/

           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/AppDB","root","mypassword");




            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
            }


            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

My .Jsp class

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload to Database Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>File Upload to Database Demo</h1>
        <form method="post" action="uploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter First Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="20"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="20"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Portrait Photo: </td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="photo" size="20"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Display Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h3><%=request.getAttribute("Message")%></h3>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error indicates that the form is not even getting to the servlet.

You defined the `action` attribute in the form as `uploadServlet` which doesn't seem to be a valid URL for your application.

The servlet's URL is defined in the `@WebServlet` annotation as `FileUploadDBServlet`.

So you can fix it by changing the action in the form or changing the URL for the servlet.

Comment: Thanks i changed that but now i get null, that was helpful. Why do you think am gettin null?

Comment: photo
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
967605
image/jpeg What am getting.

Comment: Sounds like the JDBC driver jar file is not on your classpath.  If you have more questions it's better to post a new question so other people get a chance to see it.

Comment: No its just this one so where should it put the jar? i have it in my web content src